# What does the syntax d._children = d.children; stand for in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In various examples on tree visualizations such as this [collapsible tree](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083) example the syntax `d._children = d.children;` is used. For example in this code block from the example above:

```
// Toggle children on click.  
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}
```

What does the syntax `d._children` exactly mean? To me it was not clear
where this is defined and if it's d3.js specific or JavaScript syntax in general.

Any tips on tree traversal tutorials which involve such schemes are more then welcome!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`_children` is just a temp variable that holds the children when they are hidden. When you click you are either taking `children` to null and storing the children in the temp variable, or, if `children` is already null, loading them from the temp variable.

Any temp variable could have been used. There is nothing special about `_children`. It is used to show an obvious relationship to `children`.

Comment: ah I see! I'm not yet very familiar on how new objects/variables etc  are created in javascript. Thanks for the clear answer!

Answer (score 1):

I was just testing this via this example below and found that if I replaced the word `children` with anything else the tree failed to load correctly. I believe children is a required keyword. https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083

I just verified this. In order to use another keyword to define children you must use the `tree.children()` function like this:

`tree.children(function(d){
  return d.dependencies;
});`